# Is there any way to change DocuSign InPerson Email Body programmatically?

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to Add custom Email Body programmatically. It adds the Body but not able to clear the existing message

"You are the host for an in-person signing session:
Signer: Gopika
Document: test Subject"
[image]

Is there any way to clear the above text and add custom text instead.

Currently I am using the following code

var inPersonSigner = new InPersonSigner
{

```
                SignerName = signerName,  
                RecipientId = signerId,
                InPersonSigningType = "inPersonSigner",
                HostName = "test",
                HostEmail = "test@test.com"

                 ,
                EmailNotification = new RecipientEmailNotification { EmailBody = "hellow Sign", EmailSubject = "test Subject" }
            };
```

Comment: Does setting the `emailBlurb` at the root level of the envelope have a positive effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize most email messages by uploading an email resources files to your brand profile.
This [guide](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/docusign-email-resource-file-v1-1) shows all the different things you can do.

This [article](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-admin-guide-configure-branding) explains all about how to brand your DocuSign account.