# Is there any way to change the In-Person Sender user name from the DocuSign In-Person Signing Session screen

Tags: docusignapi

[Is there any way to change DocuSign InPerson Email Body programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66715262/is-there-any-way-to-change-docusign-inperson-email-body-programmatically)

Based on my above question I can't find an option to change "the In-Person Sender user name from the DocuSign In-Person Signing Session screen" using resource files. So kindly help me to Remove the Marked account name and add hostname instead.
[image]

Comment: do you want to have a different name every time? or just change it once and for all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The top "NextGen" is your name and the button "NEXTGEN" is the account name.
These can be changed by going to https://account-d.docusign.com/me/ (for developer accounts) or from the top-right menu select **Manage Profile**.

If you need different names for different envelopes, you would need to have multiple users/accounts. While you can change this programmatically, you have no way of knowing when they'll open your email.

Comment: Thnaks for the update!. I need different names for different envelope.Currently inperson signing session showing sender name. But i need Host name should be displayed insted of sender name. How can i set this programtically?

Comment: you will need to create new users for this account. then send using the user that you created with their name.

Comment: The "Sender" is the user that is logged in or used for Authentication by the API

Comment: Thanks for the prompted Reply!.

Comment: In my work flow

Lets say Users A(Sender),B(Host) and Signer C.

 Here A is the sender and B is the Host conducting in person session for User C. 
 Currently It is showing the sender Username that is A. I need to know whether any way to change this(show Host Name) without changing the sender A.

 By either programatically or by editing resource file.

Comment: What you show in your screenshot here is the name of the Sender that sent someone to the HOST. You can change it, but it will be changed for all envelopes. You cannot have it different each time. For that - you'll need to create new users for each name.